# Copy the output of find command with scp

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, scp

I am trying from a local machine, to daily check what are the new files in the server, then copy them with one scp.

I call the script with `ssh bastibast@192.168.0.200 'bash -s' < fileretriever.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -x


FILES=$(find /home/bastibast/test -type f -mtime 0 )
echo "'$FILES'"
exit
scp -T -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa bastibast@192.168.0.200:"'$FILES'" ~/test/multiplecopy
```

However nothing is copied to my local machine.

Output of echo "'$FILES'":  `'/home/bastibast/test/test2 /home/bastibast/test/test1 /home/bastibast/test/script'`

And when I run `scp -T bastibast@192.168.0.200:'/home/bastibast/test/test2 /home/bastibast/test/test1 /home/bastibast/test/script' ~/test/multiplecopy`

It works perfectly, the 3 files are copied to my local machine. Why won't it work in the script ?

Comment: is the `exit` command on purpose? after `exit` the script terminates

Comment: It is to exit the ssh connection. So the local machine connects to the remote server, finds all the new files, stores in $FILES. Then it disconnects to be able to scp all the said files from the server -I don't want the server to scp to the local machine, but the other way around. As far as I know I cannot scp without closing the previous ssh session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to do could be done way more easily by just extracting the output of the command find into a variable with ssh

`FILES=$(ssh bastibast@192.168.0.200 -- find /home/bastibast/test -type f -mtime 0 2>&1)`

And then scp from there.